# Compile Swift project in Xcode without code signing

Tags: xcode, signing

Is there any way, any way at all, any way, I can get Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b) to allow me to create an application without code signing? I will sign my code in 6 months when I have finished writing it, but now, I just want to compile code, play, and just get HelloWorld to work. I do not want a work-around to get around my signing failure, whatever it is, I just do not want it signed and get rid of all this hassle just now. [XCode General Tab Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgnsF.jpg) and  [XCode Build Settings Tab Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6wer.jpg). This really should not be this difficult.

I just uploaded the signing error, when it is all configured to not sign [image: Signing error even when no signing]

Comment: If your application is written in html css, javascript and runs in a browser then you don't need to go through the provisioning file stuff.  if it's written in objective-c and compile for the apple app store, you will need to get your certificates worked out first before you can deploy the app anywhere for testing.  There was a nice channel 9 video from microsoft on how to go about the iphone stuff last month around Nov 22.

Comment: It is a Swift HelloWorld app. Really, I cannot just turn off all this signing crap to write HelloWorld?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid code signing so much to bother asking a question about it here on SO? You can do code signing with a free developer ID, so I don't see any reason for not wanting to sign your app.

Comment: David, turning on or turning off signing with my real AppleID makes no difference. Xcode is complaining about this signing no matter what I do. All I want to do is compile HelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

You can build and run in the simulator if you de-select "Automatically Manage Signing" or select Team: None

Running on a real device requires a free developer account and (hopefully) if you select "Automatically Manage Signing" everything will be taken care of for you, or prompt you with what you need to do.

Comment: Hi PeejWeej, no this does not work either. No matter what I do I just cannot get a silly HelloWorld application to compile without Xcode complaining about signing.

Comment: I verified that you can run helloworld in the iOS Simulators.  It will not run on a connected iphone Device without a valid provisioning profile. Note.  my environment already has some provisioning stuff and cerficates.  I just uncheck the signing box in my verification test.

Comment: I just want it to run in the iOS Simulator. As you can see from the screenshot however, I do not get that far, it complains no matter what I do at compile time about a signing certificate

Comment: @Steve So if you create a new blank project, uncheck "Automatically Manage Signing", it doesn't allow you build or run?

Comment: From the two errors in your screenshot, you have a Device targeted and not a iOS Simulator (iPhone 8 plus). Verified that those errors appear when a Device is the target or Generic iOS Device is selected and a Build action is run.

Comment: Yeah...you're targeting a real device. Not a simulator. Click on it and you should get a dropdown.

Comment: Here is a video of what I see https://www.dropbox.com/s/0aivjn42rh1q8xe/xcodeScreenRecording.mov?dl=0

Comment: Aha, PeejWeej, I see, that is a subtle change in the UI. I had not noticed I was connected to a real device! I am charging my iPhone up connected to my MacBook, and this explains why it was working before, and not now, it automatically changed! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. When you connect a device Xcode usually automatically selects it. It'll getchya :) Happy coding!